# Найти общие строки в двух текстовых файлах

Tags: строки, текст, grep

Есть два файла с цифровыми значениями, каждое с новой строки.

Сравниваю их через `grep -F -f 2.txt 1.txt > 3.txt`

В итоге в 3.txt выводятся общие строки + не верные значения.

Например, в 1.txt была строка со значением `225110`
А в 2.txt была строка со значением `22511055`
В итоге в 3.txt выводится `22511055`

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы выводились только полностью идентичные значения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используй ключ `-w`

```
grep -w -F -f 2.txt 1.txt > 3.txt
```